# How To Get The Position of A Substring

Tags: java, position, substring

I'm trying to get the position of multiple substrings in my string. I'm using a tokenizer to go through the words in the string if that may be of importance.

For example, if my input was:

> "Hello < shaz = 2"

I would like to get the position of each element such that

```
Hello : Pos 1
< : Pos 7
shaz : Pos 9
= : Pos 14
2 : Pos 16
```

I've tried using the following as an example:

```
String string = "Hello, my name is";
System.out.println(string.indexOf("my") + 1);
```

This printed 8, as I wished but I would like to get the position of every substring.

Comment: What is the general format of your input strings?

Comment: They're strings but anything can be put in. I'm using a scanner and separating the strings into in array list using a tokenizer. I was thinking, though, to get the position, I would need to do it before it is put in an array. @PM77-1

Comment: As long as you keep all the characters you can do simple arithmetic using lengths of your sub-strings.

Comment: @PM77-1 okay thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Give this edited version a try:

```
String source = "Hello < shaz = 2 Hello < shaz = 2 Hello";
String[] parts = Pattern.compile(" ").split(source);
int startIndex = 0;
for(String part: parts){        
    System.out.println(part + " : Pos " + (source.indexOf(part, startIndex) + 1));
    startIndex += part.length() + 1;
}
```

Prints:

Hello : Pos 1

< : Pos 7

shaz : Pos 9

= : Pos 14

2 : Pos 16

Hello : Pos 18

< : Pos 24

shaz : Pos 26

= : Pos 31

2 : Pos 33

Hello : Pos 35

Comment: Would not work correctly if you have two identical tokens.

Comment: @PM 77-1 - Nice catch!  I made some edits to the original.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Matcher`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html):

```
String string = "Hello, my name is";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\w+"); // search for word, the regex might need adjustment
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);
// Will print the word and it's position
while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.format("%d:%s%n", matcher.start() + 1, matcher.group());
}
```

#### Output:

> 1:Hello
>   8:my
>   11:name
>   16:is

Comment: It worked perfectly. I just need to get operators accounted for but I'm going to work with it tonight.

Thank you!

Comment: @DontPrayForMe If you change the regex to `\\S+` you will get the same output as in your example with operators but you will also get `Hello,` so you need the correct regex depending on what exactly you need to get.

Comment: @PM77-1 Don't know what he's doing (probably using `String.split()`) he needs it to create matcher which has `start` method (if he wants to use my solution).